# Get a link's "href" using mechanize

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I wanna get href value of a link with a specific class name (in this case class name contains word fbxWelcomeBoxBlock)

I tried

```
@agent = Mechanize.new
page=@agent.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
mylinks=page.links_with(:class => 'fbxWelcomeBoxBlock _8o _8s lfloat _ohe')
puts mylinks.size  # prints zero now...
```

but it didnt work . (I am using mechanize in ruby now)

Comment: Trying to get the links from something that doesn't exist yet seems odd. Shouldn't you `get` before parsing?

Comment: I copy pasted wrong, the mylinks line was after page

Answer (score -1):

It's fully dynamic page. Mechanize does not execute JS.

Comment: what do u mean ? so mechanize is not capable of returning a link with a specific dom_class name?

Comment: go to facebook.com and view source (not "inspect", just view raw page source).

Comment: If you need to execute JavaScript, you'll need something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

Comment: @tadman I do not intend to do any java script, I just want to find the link that has a CSS class name of such

Comment: once again. content of body in www.facebook.com is EMPTY. no. content. at. all. it's all JS which generates all the page at runtime. to get your link with that class you want to find you need to execute JS which will generate some DOM with this link. mechanize does not execute any JS. is it clear?

Comment: @MedyaGh You need to look at the **source** you're getting back through a tool like `curl`, not whatever ends up rendered in the DOM **after** all the client-side JavaScript has had a chance to do its thing.

Comment: @tadman I don't want to use curl,  I want use mechanize, in mechanize API see, links_with...search but I dont know how to make it wok

Comment: If you're not willing to do some simple **diagnostics** using another tool, I cannot help you. Look at the raw source of the page before any scripting is applied. You are not going to find what you expect. All this aside, why not just use the Facebook API?

Comment: @MedyaGh to write something you need to be able to read something first. go repeat your elementary school, please.