# mechanize ruby - how do do wait for a javascript based update to a page?

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

mechanize ruby (i.e. http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/) - how do do wait for a javascript based update to a page?

I have a site that requires login, but then takes many seconds to login, but after which it's really handled (it appears) as javascript.

Like is there a way to refresh the results of:

```
 page = agent.submit(login_form)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908915/get-a-links-href-using-mechanize - minute ago

Comment: Just like @iced is saying: mechanize doesn't handle js.  As an alternative, you could use a webdriver-based solution (e.g. selenium, gebish, watir).

Comment: oh, oh well then  :(  thanks for pointing this out